# Lazy/Enforced Initialization of Primitive Typed Property in C#

Tags: c#, primitive-types, lazy-initialization

Often when coding in C# I like to use this pattern for a lazy getter property:

```
private string _myProp;
string MyProp => _myProp ?? (_myProp = getMyProp());
```

I think this is pretty standard C# practice. The function `getMyProp()` is just some function that computes and returns a `string`. It is called just once to initialize the property, and henceforth it's cached. I can use this for any `object` type I like, not just `string`. However, when I try to do it for a primitive type like an int, I run into an issue. For example, if I try the following:

```
private int _operationCount;
int OperationCount => _operationCount ?? (_operationCount = GetOperationCountFromUser());
```

I get a compiler error here. It says:

> Error CS0019  Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

I understand the error means that int is a primitive type, so we can't apply the null-checking operator to it, because an `int` is never null. But is there any way I can achieve what I want here? I'm looking for a solution with the following:

- On the first access, the `int` property is initialized to the return value of the function call.
- On subsequent accesses, the `int` property is retrieved from a loaded variable in memory i.e. the function is not called again.

#### Update: Why Write Properties Like This?

The original question just cited "laziness" as the reason for writing one of these properties, but as I collaborated on this question I realised that probably the primary use case I have for the above pattern using the `??` operator is enforced initialization. By forcing initialization of a property this way, it'll always be initialized the first time you access it. Meaning you don't have to worry about injecting an initial value into multiple constructors- which clutters them up on the one hand and also isn't reliable because you might forget to initialize in one of the constructors.

Comment: FYI with C# 8 you can now write that as `string MyProp => _myProp ??= getMyProp();`

Comment: Have you considered using `Lazy` instead?

Comment: Yes - I suppose I am asking _why_ you aren't using it? Your question mentioned `Lazy` multiple times - so I am asking why you chose not to use the "obvious" solution.

Comment: @mjwills To be more correct, the question mentions "lazy" rather than `Lazy` explicitly. Actually, I did try to use `Lazy` and it wouldn't compile unless the backing property was static. Which isn't always possible. But it's a valid use case in some cases, so I think having both options is important. Hmmm... I'm starting to realize probably the main reason I use these properties isn't really laziness, it's enforcing initialization...

Comment: In which case, consider `string MyProp { get; set;  }= getMyProp();` (if it compiles).

Comment: @mjwills I've been thinking about that for a while now and the conclusion is that `string MyProp { get; set; }= getMyProp();` is a valid solution if the backing function `getMyProp()` is static. Usually this isn't the case for me, but it's a valid use case & solution for sure, similar to Sergey's. Note, the error you get if the backing property is non-static is: `CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non -static field, method, or property`

Comment: Awesome, great to hear @ColmBhandal.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make the backing type nullable, and put a call to the `Value` property on the RHS:

```
private int? _operationCount;
public int OperationCount => _operationCount ?? (_operationCount = GetOperationCountFromUser()).Value;
```

Here's a full working solution with a dummy implementation of the backing function:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        X x = new X();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World " + x.OperationCount);
    }
}

class X
{
    private int? _operationCount;
    public int OperationCount => _operationCount ?? (_operationCount = GetOperationCountFromUser()).Value;
    private int GetOperationCountFromUser() => 38;
}
```

Thanks to [juharr's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr) comment, the explanation for why this works is because the compiler converts `nullable ?? expression` to `nullable.GetValueOrDefault(expresion)` when `nullable` is a `Nullable<T>`. This explains why the RHS, the default, must be a primitive type, while the LHS is the nullable type.

Comment: Actually you can make the filed `Lazy<int>` and then the property can be `public int OperationCount => _operationCount.Value;`

Comment: And the reason you don't need the `Value` on the left is because it will compile `nullable ?? expersion` to `nullable.GetValueOrDefault(expresion)` when `nullable` is a `Nullable<T>`.  Also if you did `nullable.Value ?? expression` then the left is no longer a nullable value and thus cannot be used with `??`

Comment: Yeah, the method has to be static for the initialization to work.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't see anything bad in accessing lazy object through `Value` (at least it shows you explicitly that there can be a delay when you getting the value). But you can skip even this and become very lazy. Unfortunately, you cannot define an implicit operator for conversion between two third party types, but you can inherit from `Lazy<T>` and define an implicit conversion for your type:

```
public class VeryLazy<T> : Lazy<T>
{
    public VeryLazy(Func<T> valueFactory) : base(valueFactory) { }
    public static implicit operator T (VeryLazy<T> lazy) => lazy.Value;
}
```

And usage becomes very lazy - you can use `operationCount` whenever you want to use `int`:

```
class X
{
 private readonly VeryLazy<int> _operationCount = new VeryLazy(GetOperationCountFromUser);
 public int OperationCount => _operationCount; // implicit conversion to int
 private static int GetOperationCountFromUser() => 38;
}
```

But I'm not that lazy, and I find code without implicit conversions more readable

```
class X
{
 private readonly Lazy<int> _operationCount = new Lazy(GetOperationCountFromUser);
 public int OperationCount => _operationCount.Value; // we see there can be delay
 private static int GetOperationCountFromUser() => 38;
}
```

Also `Lazy<T>` is better than using nullable types. Sometimes object which initialization you defer might not be available - lazy would return `null` in that case (e.g. when you tried to get something from the database, but there is no value). What would nullable field tell you in that case? You might end up trying to initialize it on each property access.

Comment: `Lazy<T>` and `int` are not types which you can modify - thus 3rd party types

Comment: Overall, you make some good points. There are cases to use Lazy, and people should consider it when writing a Lazy property. The `implicit` operator solution is pretty cool; I think it's probably too complex but nice to know. As for this "`Lazy<T>` is better than using nullable types"... sometimes, yes. It depends on use case. For example, if the backing method must be non-static, I don't think you can use a Lazy backing property. And if the backing function is not a call to a DB, and is guaranteed to always return an int, then it'll never be null, so it'll only ever be called once.

Comment: @ColmBhandal thanks, good points. Btw if you want backing method to be non-static then simply move `_operationCount` initialization to the constructor.